# Play Framework and combobox

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I have two simple entities, one is **Customer** with a basic String as customerName, and **User** with e-mail, password, and one relationship with Customer.

So a user have one customer and it is required. I have one form that i pass to my view:

```
static Form<User> formUser = Form.form(User.class);
...
...
return ok(views.html.user.index.render(formUser, Customer.find.all()));
```

In my view, I use the form helper.
For example:

```
@helper.form(routes.Users.newUser()) {
    @inputText(userForm("email"))
    @select(
        field = userForm("customer"),
        customers.map{ c =>
            c.id.toString -> c.customerName
        },
        args = '_label -> "Customer"
)
    <input type="submit" value="New" />
}
```

But on my POST method, i got an **error** on my bindFromRequest, with **"Invalid Value"** for **customer field**.

```
Form<User> filledForm = formUser.bindFromRequest();
if (filledForm.hasErrors()) {
    return badRequest(views.html.user.index.render(filledForm, Customer.find.all()));
}
User user = filledForm.get()
```

Comment: Could you post the fields for your User class?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the solution was to refer the object id instead of the Object.

```
    @select(
            EmployeeForm("legalEntity**.id"**),
            entities.map{ l =>  l.id.toString -> l.name
        },
        '_label -> "Entity"  
    )
```